# error de dialogflow a firestore Webhook call failed. Error: UNAVAILABLE, State: URL_UNREACHABLE, Reason: UNREACHABLE_5xx, HTTP status code: 500

Tags: javascript, firestore, error500, dialogflow

Tengo el siguiente extracto de mi codigo:

```
function creacionReserva(agent) {
  const reservaRef = db.collection("Reserva").doc();
  const reservaId = reservaRef.id;

  return reservaRef.set({
    usuarioRef: null,
    servicioRef: null
  }).then(() => {
    agent.setContext({
      name: 'reservaUsuario',
      lifespan: 10,
      parameters: {
        reservaId: reservaId
      }
    });

    agent.add(`Muy bien, para comenzar, por favor dame tus datos de usuario, partiendo por tu nombre y apellido ${reservaId}`);
  }).catch(error => {
    console.error('Error al crear la reserva:', error);
    agent.add('Ocurrió un error al crear la reserva. Por favor, intenta nuevamente.');
  });
}

function crearUsuario(agent) {
  const nombre = agent.parameters.person;
  const reservaContext = agent.getContext('reservaUsuario');
  const reservaId = reservaContext.parameters.reservaId;
  const usuarioRef = db.collection("Usuario").doc();

  return usuarioRef.set({
    Nombre: nombre,
    email: "",
    telefono: "",
    direccion: "",
    mascotaRef: null
  }).then(() => {
    const usuarioId = usuarioRef.id;
    const reservaRef = db.collection("Reserva").doc(reservaId);

    return reservaRef.update({
      usuarioRef: usuarioId,
      servicioRef: null
    }).then(() => {
      agent.add(`Por favor, indícame tu correo electrónico. ${usuarioId}`);
    }).catch(error => {
      console.error('Error al actualizar la reserva:', error);
      agent.add('Ocurrió un error al actualizar la reserva. Por favor, intenta nuevamente.');
    });
  }).catch(error => {
    console.error('Error al crear el usuario:', error);
    agent.add('Ocurrió un error al crear el usuario. Por favor, intenta nuevamente.');
  });
}
```

en la funcion creacionReserva guardo en firestore una coleccion reserva con los datos de referencia a la coleccion de usuarios y luego creo un contexto para pasarle la id de la coleccion reserva recién creada.
Y en la funcion crearUsuario intento almacenar los parametros del contexto creados en la funcion reserva para despues de guardar los datos de usuario en este caso el nombre, actualizar el dato usuarioRef de la tabla reserva con la id del usuario recien creado.
Cuando se llega al intent que llama la funcion crearUsuario se cae dialogflow y nos manda el siguiente error Webhook call failed. Error: UNAVAILABLE, State: URL_UNREACHABLE, Reason: UNREACHABLE_5xx, HTTP status code: 500.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the code used HTTP requests instead of https. Hence the URLs were not publicly accessible and this leads to the error.

The website should also have an SSL certificate. Setting up a self-signed certificate is not enough as Dialogflow doesn’t support it.

https://bobcares.com/blog/webhook-500-internal-server-error/

Comment: ¡Estás en [es.so]! El idioma oficial del sitio es el español. No olvides traducir tu respuesta.